# Was this NAA flag correctly declined, it looks like the answer should have been a comment?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I'm partly trying to calibrate what should or shouldn't be flagged as NAA. I've seen [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) but I would appreciate input on an answer I flagged.

First the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65088417/1075247):

> Finally managed to pass a token as a get parameters instead of trying to use axios.

And second is my flag + the decline message:

[image: Flag declined page, the flag message and response is below.]

My flag

> "there's insufficient detail here to answer the question for anybody who has the same issue. It's better off as a comment or being edited by the OP. I got here as the top result from Google, and it's completely useless."

The declined message says:

> Declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

When I am moderating elsewhere in the network, I check a) if there's an attempt at answering the question, and b) if it would have been better off as a comment or edit.

I'm happy to admit there was an attempt here, but I thought this would have been better as a comment or edit? Brad in the question comments already suggests this though, so YMMV I guess. I can't use anything in this 'answer' and I don't know if anybody else can either?

Was I wrong to raise the flag?

Comment: It offers a solution, and so is an answer. It may be low-quality, and so *may* be worthy of down-votes. And the question may be worthy of close-votes (or down-votes) for possibly being non-reproducible since it appears to be an XY-Problem type question, one which may not be solvable as originally asked.

Comment: Moderators are not known for being an SME. Besides the answer did had one upvote before you casted your downvote. A mod might be sensitive to that fact. An alternative could have been to post a del-pls with reason in moderation focused chatroom. SOCVR could be an option, maybe the tag specific rooms take such requests as well.

Comment: Basically, yes. B) is not part of the NAA definition in SO - the rule of thumb to not get your NAA flag declined is only flagging posts with no attempt at all. Might seem counter-intuitive, but this is how NAA flags are handled. I don't have the bandwidth to link to the canonical Q&A right now, but I am sure others will do so below :)

Comment: I declined, and I'm most definitely not an SME, but to me, the answer reads "The api expected authentication as an API token passed in query parameters, not as an authorization header". It's a low-quality answer in need of some editing, but it doesn't appear low-quality enough to warrant deletion or comment conversion. This may be completely useless to you, but as @HovercraftFullOfEels said, it is an answer. Might not be the answer _you_ need, but it's an answer someone else might need. The question is likely a problem as well, but deleting the answer will not fix the question

Comment: To me it reads "Finally I found a way to solve the problem but not going to say how. I stopped using the library." unless not using axios counts as an answer, I fail to see what the answer is.

Comment: @ayhan Well, then you accidentally ignored the "pass a token as a get parameters" part, which is important here. The comment under the question suggests exactly that and the answer tells us that this was the right approach.

Comment: @Zoe First, I appreciate your answer here, and what you say makes sense. I'd hesitate to call myself an SME either, but I've been looking in this space recently and I'm not sure (hence my question here) how useful it is to somebody else.

Comment: @Tom but it doesn't give any details on how or why. In fact the comment under the question has more information than this answer. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That's not important for that NAA-Flag. You can still downvote it or cast a delete vote yourself, if you have the required reputation, but not a reason for a flag.

Comment: @tom not enough rep to delete... Yet!  I'll bear that in mind though.

Comment: @Tom Yes, after reading Brad's comment I realized that refers to an earlier part of the process. I thought the solution was something that replaces the axios call but apparently it became obsolete.

Comment: One thing that I want to point out is "it should be a comment".  While it doesn;t seem like it all the time, comments are intended to ask clarifying questions.  they shouldn't be for partial half answers.  So just converting it to a comment because it isn't a good answer doesn't seem like an good way of handling it.  It should be left as an answer so it can be edited into shape and/or voted on and/or deleted as appropriate.  Just moving it to a comment seems like it makes it harder to actually moderate

Comment: @psubsee2003 yeah I do agree here. If I wanted to talk for longer on how I moderate where I have a diamond, I might have added something like "And if it wouldn't make a *good* comment, I'd just delete it"

Comment: Remember that NAA and other flags are reviewed by moderators out of context; the moderators are not necessarily subject-matter experts so they aren't necessarily able to tell whether or not it is an answer to *this* question from context. So effectively NAA means not an answer to *any* on-topic question that might be asked. This answer looks like it could be an answer (though not a great answer) to a question like "how can I pass a token?".

Comment: @kaya3 aye but that is where the non-consensus starts to come into play. Does NAA mean "Not an Attempt to Answer" (this question) or does NAA mean "Not an Attempt to Answer" (any question). You are right to say that the latter is pretty much a prevailing way of handling the flag in most cases, but if it makes sense... harder to sell.

Comment: It makes sense out of necessity, since we don't have moderators covering every area of expertise. In an ideal world it wouldn't make sense, sure.